# Why is the genetic code so heavily conserved?

Tags: genetics, molecular-genetics, mutations, genetic-code, trna

Except [some organisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_code#Alternative_genetic_codes), most organisms follow the same [Genetic Code](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d6/GeneticCode21-version-2.svg)

tRNAs, tRNA synthetases, ribosomes, etc. comprise the translational machinery for converting nucleotide codons to proteins.

*My question is:*

Why is the genetic code so heavily conserved across life, given that the genes for the translational components noted above presumably vary significantly across evolution?

Comment: Can you cite any sources or point to anything that indicates where you got your information? Note that the genetic code is not the same for all organisms: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_code#Alternative_genetic_codes

Comment: It looks like you might be looking at this or something like it: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3783965/ Note that while tRNA genes sometimes go into the nucleolus, they do not leave the chromosomes. It is just that the tRNA part of the chromosome goes to hang out in the nucleolus for a while!

Comment: @MaximilianPress my bad, I didn't google alternative genetic codes, because I thought only one existed. Still, the vast majority of organisms (Except mitochondrial genes of some organisms) follow the same genetic code. I will add edits to my question.

Comment: @MaximilianPress You mean that tRNA are synthesised from chromosomes the same way mRNA are (by transcription)?

Comment: Even if they are synthesized from DNA, what if that specific part of DNA (which codes for tRNA) undergoes variation?
Wouldn't that lead to large diversity of genetic codes, possibly one for each species?
Why is it not the case?

Comment: I suggest that you read more about the evolution of translation and transfer RNAs, they are not stable in their sequence (e.g. https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fgene.2014.00303/full). While in general the genetic code and the translational apparatus is remarkably conserved (and therefore a good argument for a single origin of life), it is by no means "frozen" or identical across all organisms.

Comment: [tRNAviz](https://trna.ucsc.edu/tRNAviz) is a neat tool from the Lowe lab that allows you to visualize the structure and sequence variation of tRNA isotypes across the tree of life.

Comment: looking at update to question: what do you mean by "vast diversity of genetic codes"? I am sure that the nucleotide sequence variation underlying the genetic code is "vast", but that is probably not what you mean. I am not sure what "vast" diversity of a qualitatively-defined multidimensional construct looks like. If you are confused about evolutionary stasis, why it's hard to get "better" than the existing code, that would be a more answerable question.

Comment: @acvill that link seems to be broken, this one works: http://trna.ucsc.edu/tRNAviz/summary/

Comment: @MaximilianPress Thanks!

Comment: I  suggest you reflect on what happens if a single mutation occurs in a gene during evolution. There is a chance that it can be lethal, beneficial or neutral. Now, how many mutations would occur in a bacterium of 1000 genes if a mutation of the anticodon of a tRNA caused the wrong amino acid to be inserted everywhere it occurred? And what effect would that have? So the question — which is not easy to answer — is really, how did the alternative genetic codes ever evolve?

Comment: @MaximilianPress >what do you mean by "vast diversity of genetic codes"< Explaining in detail: Think that all living organisms evolved from a single cell which had some DNA. Now, without variation, that single DNA would get replicated exactly as it is, and all that would exist on earth today would be single celled organisms. Because of variation, that DNA changed to large diversity of genomes unique to each organism.

Comment: @MaximilianPress My question: If tRNA is formed from DNA, then it should be subject to mutation and crossing over. That, in my opinion, should lead to an unique genetic code in each organism, which is not the case.

Comment: @David, do you mean "there obviously may have been mutations of tRNA anticodons, and that would effectively kill the organism in which that mutation occured."? If that is what you mean, what if a human zygote undergoes such a mutation? If that isn't what you mean, please explain more.

Comment: Comments are not places to answer questions but to suggest improvements in them or ask for clarification. Improvement (or withdrawal) of your question can, in my opinion, be made if you think a little more about the consequences of your proposition. I say nothing about what "obviously" must have occurred, only ask you to think of the consequences. How many mutations would a mutation in the anticodon that changed the amino acid specificity potentially cause in the case I mentioned? One, 1000, 5000? Could an organism (zygote or whatever) survive the larger numbers?

Comment: And you might edit your title to express what your idea properly. Transfer RNAs of all organisms are not "the same" — the relationship between anticodon and cognate amino acid conforms to the standard genetic code in most cases.

Comment: @MaximilianPress — Whether or not your edit makes it a good question, it clearly does not reflect the concern (albeit misguided) of the OP. And ribosomes and tRNA synthetases are red herrings. A more interesting case study would be of the original amber and ochre mutations that led to the identification of stop codons.

Comment: @David Following this over-long comment discussion, I see OP as being principally concerned about stability of the genetic code across evolution. From this point of view, I see the edit as directly reflecting the concern of the OP. I believe that a fixation on tRNAs is an over-reductive view on this _very_ complex problem. If you or OP would like to roll back and propose a more appropriate edit, I invite you to do so.

Comment: @MaximilianPress thanks for the edit. It exactly is my concern.

Comment: @AsmitKarmakar Thanks for confirmation. I have now attempted an answer, as I think that this is easier to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a variety of posts on this site already that address related questions:

- [History of ideas about the form of the genetic code](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/65734/history-of-ideas-about-the-form-of-the-genetic-code)
- [Why 20 amino acids instead of 64?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/653/why-20-amino-acids-instead-of-64)
- [Is there recent info about the hypothetical ancient two-codon genetic code?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/74011/is-there-recent-info-about-the-hypothetical-ancient-two-codon-genetic-code)
- [How did the genetic code evolve?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/10009/how-did-the-genetic-code-evolve)

I don't believe that any of these answers specifically address the high conservation of the code, except as implicit (though I could be missing something).

### A useful paper

However, one such post links to [this paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3293468/) that discusses the evolution of the genetic code.

Part of the introduction restates the question's motivation rather well, I think:

> The fundamental question is how these regularities of the standard code came into being, considering that there are more than $10^{84}$ possible alternative code tables if each of the 20 amino acids and the stop signal are to be assigned to at least one codon.

In other words, why has this space of $10^{84}$ codes not been more widely explored than we observe in nature?

The first part of the paper's abstract seems relevant (I have bolded a few sections that might be taken as explanatory hypotheses):

> The genetic code is nearly universal, and the arrangement of the codons in the standard codon table is highly non-random. The three main concepts on the origin and evolution of the code are the stereochemical theory, according to which codon assignments are dictated by physico-chemical affinity between amino acids and the cognate codons (anticodons); the **coevolution theory, which posits that the code structure coevolved with amino acid biosynthesis pathways**; and the **error minimization theory under which selection to minimize the adverse effect of point mutations and translation errors was the principal factor of the code’s evolution**. These theories are not mutually exclusive and are also compatible with the frozen accident hypothesis, i.e., the notion that the standard code might have no special properties but was fixed simply because all extant life forms share a common ancestor, with **subsequent changes to the code, mostly, precluded by the deleterious effect of codon reassignment**.

They then review a variety of evidence for each theory, from which I will present one example.

### Is the genetic code optimal?

They note [a 1991 paper](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/1960738/) that used biophysical properties of amino acids and estimated that a randomly selected genetic code was ~0.01% likely to be at least as robust as the existing genetic code. In other words, the code seems to have at least somewhat minimized possible errors. So, the existing code is at least well above-average in terms of possible codes, and it's possible that the reason no better codes have been explored is that it's trapped in a local minimum of the code landscape (see Figure 3 from that paper here).

[image: Figure 3 from Koonin and Novozhilov 2012, showing possible genetic code adaptive landscape.]

They go on to discuss this in more detail. I personally find other evidence about the "coevolution" and "collective evolution" theories interesting, but obviously it is hard to repeat a multibillion year experiment.